# How can I use conditions from 2 scopes on 2 models together

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope, associations

I have the following models, which both currently have the same scope:

programme.rb

```
has_many: :campaigns
scope :visible, -> { where(status: 1) }
```

camapaign.rb

```
belongs_to: programme
scope :visible, -> { where(status: 1) }
```

I would like to edit the `campaign` scope to only search through the `programmes` which are visible. Ideally I would like to change that scope to be:

(most likely in a function)

```
def self.visible
Programme.visible.campaigns.where.(status: 1)
end
```

But this is returning:

```
undefined method `campaigns' for #<Programme::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8c9677cd68>
```

Can someone explain why I can't do this? Also, if any solution to this would be appreciated? preferably without using `.joins` (But I'll take what I can get at this point)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question whether `status` is an attribute of Programme, Campaign, or both.

Assuming both, you could do this:

```
# class Programme
has_many :campaigns
scope :visible, -> { where(status: 1) }

# class Campaign
belongs_to :programme
scope :visible, do
  joins(:programme).
    merge(Programme.visible).
    where(status: 1)
end
```

With this setup, `Campaign.visible` will only return Campaigns that belong to visible Programmes (and where `status == 1`, not sure if that means "visible" in your app).

As for why you can't call

```
Programme.visible.campaigns.where(status: 1)
```

`campaigns` is a collection that belongs to a *single* Programme. It doesn't make sense to ask a *collection* of Programmes for its campaigns.